# Drawing multiple images with Graphics in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I want to create a test project to improve my Graphics in Java. What my goal is, is to do a simple Tic Tac Toe game wich the player can input using Numpad where they want their next move.

What I am doing now is I am drawing the Background to the frame / layout for Tic Tac Toe. 
When I try to draw the X or the O on top of the background/layout it won't show up. I also tried to paint the X and O next to the background but it just won't work.

Should I update it and if so how do I update it or is it just not possible. I just can't figure it out.

I have 4 separate classes for this.

The first class is Frame. 
Second Background.
Third InputHandler.
Fourth Turn.

Here is the code:

***Frame***

```
package Game;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private Background bg;
    private Turn trn;
    private InputHandler in;

    public Frame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Hi");
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
        bg = new Background();
        add(bg);
        trn = new Turn();
        add(trn);
        setVisible(true);

        in = new InputHandler();
        addKeyListener(in);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }
}
```

***Background***

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Background extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public Background() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/tiles/tile_TicTacToeGrid.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.\n\n" + e);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // Drawing to screen
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

***InputHandler***

```
package Game;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class InputHandler implements KeyListener {

    private Turn turn;


    public InputHandler() {
        turn = new Turn();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int k = e.getKeyCode();

        if (k == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1) {
            turn.play();            
        }
        if (k == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2) {
            turn.play();
        }
        if (k == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3) {
            turn.play();
        }
        if (k == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4) {
            turn.play();
        }
        if (k == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD5) {
            turn.play();
        }
        if (k == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6) {
            turn.play();
        }
        if (k == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD7) {
            turn.play();
        }
        if (k == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8) {
            turn.play();
        }
        if (k == KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9) {
            turn.play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        //
    }
}
```

***Turn***

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import tiles.Draw;

public class Turn extends JPanel{

    public char nextTurn = 'O';
    public BufferedImage image;
    private Draw draw;

    public Turn() {
    }

    public void pTurn() {
        if (nextTurn == 'O') {
            nextTurn = 'X';
        } else if (nextTurn == 'X') {
            nextTurn = 'O';
         }
    }

    public void play() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/tiles/tile_X.png"));
            System.out.println("X Found");
            pTurn();
            repaint();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File not found\n" + e);
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 200, 200, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Db3cC5iPrOM

Comment: @Leo Thanks but I know how to do it with buttons. I want to be able to use the Graphics class to draw an Image on top of another Image

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). 2) One way to get images for an example is to hot-link to images listed in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: You add `bg` and `turn` to a component using `GridLayout`; that does not place them atop each other like you intend. Also, you should override `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`, and only create swing components in the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).